# Android Background Image larger than container

Tags: android, background, imageview, crop, gravity

We are starting to develop Android apps coming from iOS development and are having difficulty working with background images.

We have a background image 1024 x 1200 that we want centered in a view horizontally and top aligned. We do not want the image to be scaled but want the image to overflow / clip so it sits correctly in the view. Something like you would achieve with CSS background-position: top center;

We've tried a few approaches but are always getting a scaled image. Combinations of setScaleType(), setAdjustViewBounds(), setting gravity via LayoutParams and various other things have had no success. We're now a bit stuck on what to try next.

The idea is that we can use a single image for multiple screen sizes without having the image resize (we will have 2 or 3 of these images for screen size/density ranges). This is to reduce the number of these images we need to cover all the android screen possibilities.

Craig

Comment: It might not fix your problem, but if you have set your image in the `background` attribute, the scaletypes won't work. If you want to use them, you will need an `ImageView` with the image set in the `src` attribute.

Comment: Basically, what you'll want is an ImageView, the scaletype set to centercrop and top|center_horizontal as layout_gravity.

Answer (score 1):

create a layer-list:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

In this layer-list layer a background (a solid rectangle of a desired colour), and the image as a bitmap tag (this bitmap tag will prevent scaling) and set the desired gravity of the image. make sure to put the image as the last item in the layer-list, as it levels bottom to top. then set this drawable as the background.

This will have a coloured background, in case from some reason the image doesn't fill the entire screen, and the image will no be scaled and will follow the desired gravity attribute.